# Auto-navigation for checkboxes and radio groups

Tags: docusignapi

The auto-navigation in the signing interface works exactly opposite to the way I expect it to for checkboxes and radio groups.  Is there a way to fix or customize this auto-navigation?

For radio groups, I expect the auto-navigation to move forward, past the rest of the radio group, after selecting any one option.  What actually happens, is that the auto-navigation stops on every option in the group, even if I've already selected one.

For check boxes, I expect the auto-navigation to stop on every checkbox.  What actually happens, is that the auto-navigation moves forward, past the remaining checkboxes after I select any one of them.  The only way to fill in the other checkboxes is to scroll back up each time.

The only configuration option I can find is to switch to page-only navigation, but that solution makes signing difficult and is worse than the checkbox / radio group problem.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of using the configuration setting that you already mentioned (i.e., "**Signing auto-navigation rule**"), I'm not aware of any other way to control how navigation (focus) functions within an Envelope.